# How do I render divs horizontally without using flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I'm designing a website with ReactJS and Typescript and I want the pages each to live on a Card and when the user uses the Navigation bar, the current card slides away and the new one slides in. I am using `react-transition-group` to accomplish this. I eventually want to add direction to it, but I'm stuck at an earlier hurdle.

It's all working well, the current route exists, the new one loads off-screen, the current one slides away and the new one slides in.

My problem is that the new component is rendering on a new line each time - not inline with the current one. This causes a jerky jump down and then up.
I have tried to fix it by making my parent container `display: flex;` and each of my children `flex: 1`, but as you can imagine, this causes some really weird results mid-transition with the width of both components. I also tried to fix that by changing the flex to `flex: 1 1 100%` and some other variants, but to no avail.

I did put my App.tsx here, but honestly - it doesn't feel that relevant. If you feel like you need it though - just let me know. The basic structure is:

```
<div id='main>
    <Route exact path={path} key={title}>
        <CSSTransition
            classNames='mainCard'
            nodeRef={refQuery}
            unmountOnExit
        >
            <div
                className='mainCard'
                ref={refQuery}
            >
                <Component />
            </div>
        </CSSTransition>
        ...
    </Route>
</div>
```

and my `_animations.scss` has:

```
.mainCard-enter {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
.mainCard-enter-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
.mainCard-exit {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
.mainCard-exit-active {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Then, in my custom.scss, I've been trying to fix the problem with:

```
#main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .mainCard {
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

I also gave it a go with css grid, but it's not something that I've had much practice with so I couldn't work it out.

*NOTE: This project uses Bootstrap, so if you have a class-y (See what I did there?) way to fix it - I'm good with that too.*

Pleases and thank yous in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the idea of the project changed quite a bit, but the general fix here was that I needed to use `transform: translate3d()` instead!